# Facebook site url - redirect to different urls within same domain

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook app on developers.facebook.com and specified a site url for my website. When users on my website login with facebook it redirects them back to the site url I specified (e.g. example.com) on the facebook app settings.

I also have a mobile web site which has facebook login but when users login from the mobile site (mobile.example.com) it still redirects to the main site (example.com).

How can I make facebook redirect to either example.com or mobile.example.com depending on where the facebook login request comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook allows you to pass a variable named `state` to the auth dialog. This value gets returned by Facebook on both success or failure.

The intent of the `state` variable is to prevent people from gaining access to your site with forged requests. However, you could add a string to the state variable unique to people coming from the mobile site. On your redirect page registered with your app, you just need to add code to examine the `state` variable and redirect the user if it has the "mobile" string in it.